# Mozilla Addon to auto login

Tags: firefox-addon, mozilla, autologin

I am new to Mozilla addons. I am developing a autologin addon. So far I am able to create a addon which can load a page into a tab. This page is a web site page and has 4 fields I want to automate login.
I am particularly looking at how to fill these input boxes with the data that I have currently hard coded in addon.
I am having problem in accessing the DOM for the loaded tab. I am able to catch page load event.

```
gBrowser.addEventListener("load", examplePageLoad, true);   

function examplePageLoad (event) {  
     if (event.originalTarget instanceof HTMLDocument) {
          var win = event.originalTarget.defaultView;
     }
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you can tell, `event.originalTarget` is the document object, so you can just do something like:

```
var doc = event.originalTarget;
if (doc.URL === 'http://example.com') {
  doc.getElementById('loginForm').value = getUsername();
}
```

Also take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load